# filter required members from list Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I am trying to filter a list by members of other list.

```
List1 = {{"1", "abc"}, {"566", "cde"}, {"356", "fff"}, {"76", "aaa"}}

List2 = {"2", "33", "566", "76"}
```

final list should be `{{"566, "cde"}, {"76", "aaa"}}`

I am trying this below, but does not work:

```
val result = List1.map(data => {data.filterNot(p => List2.contains(p._1)}
```

However, I do not see filter happening. result is same as `List1`

Comment: This seems to work as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/NAVc79EkQv2a8tRJVZh6Kw - Not sure why you used `map`, nor `filterNot`

Comment: Probably because `filterNot` seems somewhat counter-intuitive. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez : Even I thought this to work. There is some API, the response received and applyinf filter on that response and I do not see desired result. Anyways, it seems there is no fault in the code. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

`List1` starts with 4 elements, and you want it to end up with 2 elements? If you want to reduce the number of elements in a list, you must filter that list. Right now you're mapping it, so the result will always have the same number of elements as the input, though those elements may have changed.

Also, it looks like you've declared `List1` to be a list of lists, but then the code you've written seems to be working with it as if it's a list of list of tuples. So, I'm not sure what you actually want there.

Assuming you have a list of tuples, this is what you would want:

```scala
val list1 = List(("1", "abc"), ("566", "cde"), ("356", "fff"), ("76", "aaa"))
val list2 = List("2", "33", "566", "76")

val result = list1.filter(p => list2.contains(p._1))
```